# embeded google map with several markers

Tags: php, html, google-maps, google-maps-embed

I want to embed a google map with several locations. So far I found this html code:

```
<iframe
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyBECBmDGXDR_37hLJU-zjMSZ65OIA4Ikek
  &q=Theophiledonnéstraat+79+3540+Donk
  " allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

This works perfectly but only shows one marker. I want to add several other markers like this:

```
<iframe
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyBECBmDGXDR_37hLJU-zjMSZ65OIA4Ikek
  &q=Theophiledonnéstraat+79+3540+Donk
  &q=Dorpsstraat+29+3770+Riemst
  " allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I use this simple API because i need to add the locations based on a database request, therefore the easiest solution is to add data with PHP.

I hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with adding multiple locations as you are trying here is that there is a finite length to querystrings ( GET requests ) so you could find that too many locations will break the map.

Rather than using the method shown originally could you not create a php script ( called `iframemap.php` for example ) and use that as the source for the iframe. This php page could connect to the db to retrieve the results for whatever markers you want and geocode them at run-time. You could also save the results from the geocoding back to the db as lat/lng so that future requests use the lat/lng info from the db.

```
somepage.html ( or php, htm etc )
---------------------------------

<iframe src='iframemap.php' allowfullscreen></iframe>



iframpmap.php
-------------
<?php

    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $db     =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

    $places=array();

    $sql    =   'select `location` from `maps` limit 100';
    $res    =   $db->query( $sql );
    if( $res ){
        while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) $places[]=$rs->location;
    }
    $db->close();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset='utf-8' /> 
        <title>Google Maps i-Frame source</title> 
        <script src='https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function(){
                if( typeof( 'google' )=='undefined' ){
                    return false;
                }

                /* The contents of `places` could EASILY be derived from a database query */
                var places = [
                    'Theophiledonnéstraat+79+3540+Donk',
                    'Dorpsstraat+29+3770+Riemst',
                    'Kosterstraat+2,+3631+Maasmechelen,+Belgium'
                ];
                <?php
                    echo 'places=' . json_encode( $places ) . ';';
                ?>

                var oMap = document.getElementById('map');
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                var map = new google.maps.Map( oMap, {
                    zoom: 10,
                    draggable:true,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng( 50.805697, 5.598648 ),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });

                for( var i = 0; i < places.length; i++ ) {
                    geocoder.geocode( { address:places[ i ] }, function ( results,status ){
                        if( status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {

                            var location = results[0].geometry.location;
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position:{ lat:location.lat(),lng:location.lng() },
                                map:map
                            });
                            bounds.extend( marker.position );
                            map.fitBounds( bounds );
                        }
                    });
                }
            },false )
        </script>
    </head>
    <style>
        html, html body, #map{height:100%;width:100%;padding:0;margin:0; }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```